# HTML5 Video(mp4 format) tag is not playing on linux OS

Tags: linux, html, video

I have a problem of playing the html5 video(MP4 format) using video tag on linux. Could you please suggest What may be the problem or any alternative solution to make my video play on al l browsers along with all Operationg Systems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 doesn’t guarantee any particular video format will be supported by a browser; the solution is to use [multiple sources](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video):

A video, using the user agent default set of controls, with alternative sources:

```
<video controls>
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"
         type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1, mp4a"'>
 <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv"
         type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
 <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
```